# Is there a more elegant way to create highlights for buttons?

Tags: css

```css
.menu-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
}

.highlight {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgb(121, 121, 121);
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: none;
}

.menu-item:hover .highlight {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="highlight"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="highlight"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to achieve this highlight effect without the use of an extra div element for the highlight? I've tried to use radial gradient radial-gradient but I don't think that would work for rounded square shaped highlights.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below

```css
.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
}

.menu-item {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
}

.menu-item:hover {
  background-color: rgb(121, 121, 121);
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-item">
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the background-color up to `.menu`

```css
.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
}

.menu-item {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.menu-item:hover {
  background-color: rgb(121, 121, 121);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-item"></div>
  <div class="menu-item"></div>
</div>
```

Using pseudo-selector:

```css
.menu-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
}

.menu-item::before {
  content: '';
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: rgb(121, 121, 121);
}

.menu-item:hover::before {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-item"></div>
  <div class="menu-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, this was dumb question. Making the buttons to the size of what I want the highlights to be went completely over my head.

Comment: It's only dumb not to ask questions. :) For the pseudo-selector, I'm using `left`, `right`, instead of `width` and `height`, because I have experienced rendering problems in Safari with the latter.